# "Ionic serve" starts but not work

Tags: android, ios, cordova, browser, ionic-framework

I have a problem with my projects. I reinstalled windows in my notebook some days ago, I installed all for using ionic (I followed a tutorial, the same one that the previous time helped me install everything), but my projects not working with "ionic serve" (although it doesn't have errors either, only the message in the browser of the error and the error code: "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"). What could be the problem?

My system info:
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried running "gulp build" before "ionic serve"?

Comment: I tried, but not work :(

Comment: Yes, I did, but nothing. Thanks, I have already solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem. I had to install windows again. It seems the problem started when I installed the Visual Studio before Xampp. Maybe Visual Studio installed something weird haha.

Thanks and greetings to the forum! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following instructions in cmd:

```
ipconfig/release
ipconfig/renew
```

If it doesn't help, follow this link: http://www.toppctech.com/error-code-err_connection_timed_out/